# Untyped global name: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to write a function that computes pdf for components of gaussian mixture

```
from numba import njit
from numba_stats import norm
@njit
def gmm_pdf(obs, w, mu, sd):
    gm = np.zeros((len(obs), w.shape[0], len(mu)))
    for i in range(len(mu)):
        g = numba_stats.norm.pdf(obs, mu[i], sd[i])[:,None]*w
        gm[:,:,i] = g[:,:,i]
    return gm
```

An example

```
x = np.array([[0.1], [1.2], [-0.3], [0.85]])
mu = np.array([1.55, 9.93, 4.19])
sd = np.array([1.03, 1.67, 8.33])
w = np.array([[0.25, 0.25, 0.5],
               [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]])
```

and

```
gmm_pdf(x, w, mu, sd)
```

works well. But when I e.g. create a function

```
@njit
def foo(obs, w, mu, sd):
    d = gmm_pdf(obs, w, mu, sd)
    return(d)
```

and call

```
foo(x, w, mu, sd)
```

then I get a message

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'gmm_pdf': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example raises a different error: `NameError: name 'numba_stats' is not defined`